# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() is not working after putting .aspx file inside a different folder

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

I have written a javascript function inside a Folder named Scripts. There are two functions inside this javascript file which works as PopUp. I called those javascript function from a .cs file using  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() and its working fine.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "disp_confirm", "<script type='text/javascript'>ImgDivPopup()</script>", false);
```

But After I put the .cs file inside different folder, like View => InProcess => Traveller.cs the above code doesn't work.

Is that possible to solve this..

Comment: Are you sure that you are referencing the script that contains your `ImgDivPopup()` function within your new page? All the `RegisterStartupScript()` method does is indicate that a particular function should be called when the page is ready, but if the function isn't available, it won't work. You can use the Developer Tools (F12) in your browser to check this.

Comment: Where is the .aspx file? How you include the .js file?

Comment: Please Read the question @Shadow

Comment: I did. The function `ImgDivPopup()` is not built inside JavaScript. Somewhere, there is a text file, which defines that function. I asked where you include that file, with the function definition, because that your problem, not the code calling the function. You mentioned that the function is inside folder named "Scripts", but function can't be in a folder. I must be in a file, and you must somehow reference this file in your code.

Comment: I cannot write javascript function without having a file. The function is inside a file obviously and that file is inside the Scripts Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues that could be causing your existing problem :

**Ensure Proper Referencing**

All the `RegisterStartupScript()` method does is actually register a specific script to be added to the page (and often executed) when everything has been loaded. Your existing code will call the `ImgDivPopup()` when this occurs, which would generally work assuming that a `<script>` reference existing with that function defined :

```
<!-- Ensure you are referencing the appropriate file so you can access the function -->
<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/your-imgdivpopup-file.js") %>'></script>
```

This is just an example of how you might reference your file with your function defined, but if you are using an external file, you'll need this.

**Possible Race Condition**

If you are referencing the file and it has any other dependencies, such as another client-side library, then you could consider adding an explicit delay in calling your function to give things time to catch up :

```
// Call your function with a 10ms delay
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "disp_confirm", "setTimeout(function(){ ImgDivPopup();},10);", true);
```

**Use Your Developer Tools (F12)**

Since this is likely a client-side issue, consider using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser. Check the Network and Console tabs to see if any errors are present (such as `"function ImgDivPopup() is not defined"`, `"{your-script-file} could not be found"`, etc.)

Comment: I did it but it didn't load the function.

Comment: I added the script reference in the Master Layout File and started working. But I dont understand why can't I write  `<script src=''~/Scripts\SiteJavaScript.js">ImagePop()</script>` inside the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`. It doesn't work then. @rion

Comment: You need to use separate `<script>` tags, one to define your function (i.e `<script src='...'></script>`) and then another script to actually call your same function (i.e. `<script>yourFunction();</script>`). The approach you used, defining a `src` attribute and content on the same tag may not work reliably and is generally avoided in favor of the separate tags.